# Jquery не выполняет редирект при авторизации

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

Пользователь вводит данные авторизации. Они проверяются и отправляются на сервер. Сервер возвращает при успехе redirect, по которому jquery переходит и получает другую страницу, которая должна быть отображена в этой же вкладке браузера, с новым адресом, который пришёл в редиректе, в ответе на jquery запрос. При этом текущая страница пользователя остаётся неизменной. Как сделать, чтобы jquery отправлял запрос на сервер, не переходил по редиректу и текущая страница браузера перешла по этому редиректу?

```
$.post({
                url: "/login",
                data: data_json,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                statusCode: {

                }
            })
```

Comment: _Как решить проблему?_ Дебаг...

Comment: Без кода здесь поможет только гадалка.

Comment: В success выполняется alert, вопрос к вам, alert редиректит?

Answer (score 0):

Редирект отправляется с http статусом 301.
возможно jQuery не считает такой статус за успешный
Можно попробовать вытащить заголовки из

````
var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php", function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
  .always(function(response) {
    response //<- тут должен быть заголовок с урлом для редиректа
  });```
````

Comment: Можно ли сделать так, чтобы jquery не выполнял редирект. Потому что он переходит на другую страницу и загружает ее, а если после всех выполненных операций jquery вытащить ссылку из заголовков в применить ее к текущему окно, то это окно повторно загрузит тот же самый документ, а это есть нагрузка на сервер и костыльное решение проблемы

Comment: Или может стоит не отправлять post запрос с помощью ajax, а якобы перейти по ссылке post запросом

Comment: не отправлять post запрос, а перейти по ссылки пост запросом...
имхо масло масленое.
не пойму вам нужен редирект или нет?

Comment: обычный переход по ссылке происходит get запросом. Формы умеют отправлять post запрос. Как сделать так же из js. Потому что если jquery редиректит, тот как варинат обойтись без него, то есть отправить post запрос, как делает form, но в формате json

Comment: Тогда можно посмотреть в сторону fetch
https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch#post-zaprosy